# Tensorflow how to get tensor value

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

In python I can use

```
a = np.array([[3], [6], [9]])
```

Obviously,

```
a[0][0] = 3
a[1][0] = 6
a[2][0] = 9
```

But I tried to do the same thing with tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable(np.array([[3], [6], [9]]))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as ss:
   ss.run(init)
   for i in range(3):
       print sess.run(a[i][0])
```

If I print it(use for loop), I got `TypeError: 'Variable' object is not callable`

How can I resolve this error?
Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Your code works for me, after the typo is fixed, i.e. print (ss.run(a[i][0])

Answer (score 1):

You can define another op, that is dependent on the original variable, that contains the slice of your tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable(np.array([[3], [6], [9]]))
part = []
for i in range(3):
    part.append(a[i][0])
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as ss:
   ss.run(init)
   for op in part:
       print ss.run(op)
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Which version of tensorflow? On 0.11.0rc0 it works.

Answer (score 0):

Despite tensorflow and numpy are quite similar at the first glance, tensorflow workflow substantially differs from numpy's. When using tensorflow, you should first define the computational graph -- the rules defining the connections between tensors.

In your case, the graph consists of only one variable `a`. Once the graph was defined, you would be able to compute the values of different nodes in a graph by running a tensorflow session. In your case, to print a value of `a`, use the following code:

```
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(a))
```

Comment: I need to get the value respectively

Comment: sess.run(a) would return you variable a in a form of numpy array. You could assign the result to another variable and then iterate over it as with regular numpy array.